# возращение по ссылке через std::swap и через обычное присваивание

Tags: c++

```
func(vector<struc>& b)
{
  1. b.swap(...)
  2. b = struct_b_internal;
}
```

с++ функция возвращает структуру по ссылке
в чем разниц возвратить через swap от обычного присваивания? Через swap быстрее ???

Comment: всё зависит от реализации объекта. если у него есть быстрый оператор присваивания r-value объекта, то никакой разницы. *вопрос надо задавать полнее - пример должен быть рабочим...*

Comment: Своп делает больше работы - он он записывает что-то в `struct_b_internal`. Непонятно, зачем кому-то использовать первый вариант.

Comment: Я смутно помню, что там возможно что-то с атомарностью было связано, `swap` может из-за этого использоваться. Но не уверен.